# How do I change Android code to process two JSON from MySQL Database

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I am new to android development and have been trying very hard to wrap my head around this code, but I still need some help understanding how this JSON is processed. Not only that, I want to do something slightly different with it and would like to know how to change this code to do it.

In my existing PHP code, I query a MySQL database and make a JSON array:

```
    echo json_encode($rows1);
```

which looks like this:

```
    [
    {"id":"6","rating":"5","created":"2012-11-29 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"2","rating":"5","created":"2013-11-19 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"8","rating":"4","created":"2013-06-16 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"3","rating":"4","created":"2013-11-05 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"10","rating":"3","created":"2012-12-05 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"7","rating":"3","created":"2013-08-02 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"4","rating":"3","created":"2013-08-12 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"9","rating":"2","created":"2013-10-03 00:00:00"}
]
```

My android code looks like this:

```
    public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private final FetchDataListener listener;
    private String msg;

    public FetchDataTask(FetchDataListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if(params == null) return null;

        // get url from params
        String url = params[0];

        try {
            // create http connection
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            // connect
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);

            // get response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if(entity == null) {
                msg = "No response from server";
                return null;        
            }


            // get response content and convert it to json string
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return streamToString(is);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            msg = "No Network Connection";
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sJson) {
        if(sJson == null) {
            if(listener != null) listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }        

        try {
            // convert json string to json array
            JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(sJson);
            // create apps list
            List<Application> apps = new ArrayList<Application>();

            for(int i=0; i<aJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                Application app = new Application();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                app.setCreated(sdf1.format(sdf.parse(json.getString("created"))));
                app.setRank(json.getString("rating"));  
                // add the app to apps list
                apps.add(app);
            }

            //notify the activity that fetch data has been complete
            if(listener != null) listener.onFetchComplete(apps);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            msg = "Invalid response";
            if(listener != null) listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }

    /**
     * This function will convert response stream into json string
     * @param is respons string
     * @return json string
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String streamToString(final InputStream is) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } 
        finally {           
            try {
                is.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Now, lets say I want to make two MySQL database queries in the PHP and make two JSON arrays like this:

```
echo json_encode($rows1);
echo json_encode($rows2);
```

which looks like this:

```
    [
    {"id":"6","rating":"5","created":"2012-11-29 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"2","rating":"5","created":"2013-11-19 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"8","rating":"4","created":"2013-06-16 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"3","rating":"4","created":"2013-11-05 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"10","rating":"3","created":"2012-12-05 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"7","rating":"3","created":"2013-08-02 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"4","rating":"3","created":"2013-08-12 00:00:00"},
    {"id":"9","rating":"2","created":"2013-10-03 00:00:00"}
]

[
    {"id":"5","rating":"4","created":"2014-02-11 00:00:00"}
]
```

How would I change the android code I have to process two arrays. My goal is to populate a Listview with the original $rows1 array and populate another layout with $rows2?

Answer (score 0):

instead of printing two json strings at a time try to convert those two arrays into single array and then print json string like below

$result = array($rows1,$rows2);

echo json_encode($result);

Answer (score 0):

You can send both `jsonArrays` by adding them into single `Jsonobject` and sending the single Json object from the server to android which will be only single.

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple. You can do either of following:

- You can call FetchDataTask with different param url for every row fetch.
- You can change your FetchDataTask `doInBackground` to loop through an array of params, which you can provide for every row, and fetch those rows. e.g `row1Url = params[0], row2Url = params[1] ...` Then return an Array of String results, loop through them in your `onPostExecute` and fill your respective layouts.

Your code for AsyncTask is dependent on the layouts. You should consider to make it more reusable.